# How to delete an object from vector<ptr*>?

Tags: c++, vector

I've got classes like that:

```
class A {
        vector<B*> ve;

    public:
        void add_last(B* b)
        {
            ve.push_back(b);
        }
        void remove_last() {//????}
//....
}

class B { //...}

class B1 : public B { //...}
    public:
        ~B1 {cout << "~B1\n";}
        //...
}

class B2 : public B {
    public:
        ~B2() {cout << "~B2\n";}
        //...
}
```

And in main I do:

```
A a;
a.add_last(new B1);
a.add_last(new B2);

//...

a.remove_last();
```

I have two problems. First is that I cannot find out how should I remove this last object cause pop_back won't call a destructor. Secondly, I should use add_last (**const** B* b) but when I try do so I've got only errors... I don't know how to do any of these. It has to be done that way beacuse my professor gave some code and it has to match it.

Comment: Use a `std::vector<unique_ptr<T>>` instead of `std::vector<T*>`,  That way `unique_ptr` will manage the pointer for you.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's true judging by how the OP is using the class and by the fact that they want a destructor be called, however in general it might be that the class is *not* supposed to take ownership and merely references the objects stored elsewhere.

Comment: How does `A` know that the pointer was allocated using `new`?  What if the pointer was just the address of a local variable?  That's the flaw in the code you have now, professor or no professor.  `A a; B1 b; a.add_last(&b);` -- How would that work?

Comment: Also, `A a; a.add_last(new B1[10]);` -- How would `A` know to use `delete[]` instead of `delete`?  Hopefully your professor is giving you this code to demonstrate the holes in the class, and not giving it as the way to properly write C++ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @NathanOliver already said in the comments, the proper way to do that would be to store [`std::unique_ptr<B>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead of `B *` so that [destructors are called automatically & memory is freed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii). Furthemore, use `std::unique_ptr<const B>` to be able to insert `const B *`:

```
class A {
        vector<std::unique_ptr<const B>> ve;

    public:
        void add_last(const B* b)
        {
            ve.push_back(b);
        }

        void remove_last()
        {
            ve.pop_back();
        }
}
```

If, however, you have to use raw pointers, then you can just call `delete` yourself:

```
class A {
        vector<const B *> ve;

    public:
        void add_last(const B* b)
        {
            ve.push_back(b);
        }

        void remove_last()
        {
            delete ve.back();
            ve.pop_back();
        }
}
```

Comment: I know I can do it but my professor wants not to use it... I have to do it with "normal" pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking that the vector is not empty before calling delete, to deal with undefined errors

```
class A {
        vector<const B *> ve;

    public:
        void add_last(const B* b)
        {
            ve.push_back(b);
        }

        void remove_last()
        {
            if(!ve.empty()){
               delete ve.back();
               ve.pop_back();
             }
            
        }
}
```